# I want to add a field called 'Category' to my skills domain

Tags: grails

I want to add a field called 'Category' to my skills domain.

*Note:The category will be a pre-populated list.

Here's how my skills domain look like:

```
class Skill {

    String name
    String description
    String skillCode

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, unique: true
        description nullable: true
        skillCode nullable: true, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        name type: "text"
        description type: "text"
        skillCode type: "text"
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "${skillCode}. (${name})"
    }


}
```

What shall be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: "I want to add a field called 'Category' to my skills domain" - Does the field have to be called `Category` or can it be `category` (it makes a difference).

Comment: Pre-populated in code (an enum) or pre-populated by saving values to a Category domain object?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown It has to be `Category` For eg. Python, Java, Grails are skills but they fall under the Category Programming Languages

Comment: @Daniel Can you please elaborate on your explaination?

Comment: My question was getting clarification for how to best implement this, but now it sounds like you're more asking about `Category` vs `category`.  I'd strongly advise following best practices (always important, but even more so in grails) and naming it `category` all lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure is't the approach you wanted, but according to my understanding you are looking for the solution as below

> class Skill {
>
> ```
> String name
> String description
> String skillCode
> String category
>
> static constraints = {
>     name nullable: false, unique: true
>     description nullable: true
>     skillCode nullable: true, unique: true
>     category inList: ["Python", "Java", "Grails"]
> }
>
> static mapping = {
>     name type: "text"
>     description type: "text"
>     skillCode type: "text"
> }
>
> public String toString() {
>     return "${skillCode}. (${name})"
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: In a comment under the question Sparsh mentioned that the field name has to be `Category` and cannot be `category`.  The explanation for why that is doesn't make sense to me, but that is the expressed requirement.  If you change `category` to `Category` in your example, without making some more changes you are going to have other problems.

Comment: Don't really understand what are you trying to explain. I just answer from my understanding.